# Apache ProxyPass Reverse DNS - Forward all source files?

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I've got some websites in the local network, which have no access to the internet.
So I want to set up one machine which has the access, and use it as a reverse proxy.

My apache config looks like this:

```
ProxyPass "/website1" "http://192.168.0.1/website1"
ProxyPassReverse "/website1" "http://192.168.0.1/website1"
```

So when I access my public domain /website 1 it redirects me to the website1, but when i click something on there which forwards me to something like /website1/about, it doesn't work, because the sourcecode still says to go to http://192.168.0.1/website1/about, which is obviously not possible from outside of the local network.

So how do I get Apache to forward all files and rewrite the paths?

Or an even better question, is there something better than apache to do an reverse proxy?

complete conf: http://pastebin.com/Mhuv7YzM

Comment: Apache is great for reverse proxy. My question is how the rest of the VirtualHost looks like, can you provide us with it?

Comment: @Orphans added, but really nothing special there

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You have two options depending on what you backend does.

If the backend server modifies html links with the name of the requested host you can just add:

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
```

If you want to modify the contents of "fixed" htmnl links inside the responses you will also need "**mod_proxy_html**" functionality, which is a mod_proxy submodule specific for this.

[mod_proxy_html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't. `ProxyPassReverse` is only intended to rewrite *redirects*, not paths somewhere in the body of files. That would require pretty much complete knowledge of the content format, like HTML, SOAP, whatever, to know where paths are to be expected and replaced (like in `<a href="...">` for HTML, but also `<link>`, `<script>`, …).

What you probably want to do is simply setting up different vHosts for different reverse proxied websites, so that no rewriting of relative paths is necessary. Of course, if some links contain the domain (as seems to be the case, if I understand your question correctly), it won't work that way either and you "simply" have to configure the website on the internal host to use the correct, external domain name in links.

Answer (score 0):

I just use nginx now, it works flawless.

```
sub_filter_types        text/css;
sub_filter_once         off;
sub_filter              '192.168.0.1'  'proxy.mydomain.com';
proxy_set_header        Accept-Encoding "";

location /website1 {
    proxy_pass              http://192.168.0.1/website1;
}

location /website2 {
    proxy_pass              http://192.168.0.2/website2;
}
```

may you even want to use caching for faster access, then add this:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/www/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=nginx:10m;
proxy_cache_key $host$uri$is_args$args;
proxy_cache_valid 200 10m;
proxy_cache nginx;
```

just make sure to create the path /var/www/cache or set another existing one

Answer (score -3):

You have forgotten enabling "RewriteEngine"
Be sure that you have enabled mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http and mod_rewrite.

Adding this will propably solve it.

```
    ProxyRequests off
    RewriteEngine on
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
```

And also thoose line should look like this:

```
ProxyPass "/website1" "http://192.168.0.1/website1"
ProxyPassReverse "/website1" "http://192.168.0.1/website1"
RewriteRule ^/website1$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/website1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it's not working. Source code still looks like <script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.0.1/website1/js/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: That's why you have to use mod_rewrite also.

Comment: What modules habe you enabled?

Comment: @Orphans mod_rewrite does not modify the delivered content, it rewrites the paths in the requests that are forwarded to the internal server.

Comment: all these mods are enabled.

Comment: @lemon If you modify this src="192.168.0.1/website1/js/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></ to this : src="/website1/js/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></
It should work.

Comment: that was only an example, there are thousands of sources which i would have to edit

Comment: Take a backup and use "sed" to replace it.

Comment: may many ways lead to rome, but this is not the one i wanna go.

Comment: This answer is a compendium of wrong answers, Proxy * is used for forward proxies, which clearly is not the case and the rewriting "solution" provided solves nothing is a dirty workaround for what could be done with `ProxyPreserveHost on`

Comment: Well, apparently the solution I have working for a couple of years of the wrong solution.